# How do I specify the path to my java package?

Tags: java, string, netbeans, path

I am trying to use dynamic binding to create "`ByteCode`" objects. I am using this statement below, but I am confused about how the path should look.
In netbeans, I have a project called `interpreter` and a java package `bytecode` that holds the `ByteCode` subclasses.

I am guessing its suppose to be `("interpreter/bytecode." )` but not sure.
thanks

```
bytecode = (ByteCode)(Class.forName("path/exampl/path."+codeClass).newInstance());
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you need any path: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29). Just ```package.classname```.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the full qualified name of class to forName method.

Example:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Comment: yes, but I want to use dynamic binding to instantiate my classes.

Comment: that's why i am concatenating it with the String codeClass variable, which is the name of the class.

Comment: You can use a string variable for full name then.

Comment: so i would use periods to specify the path from the project to the package?

Comment: no need for project name, just use your fully qualified class name (package + classname) see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html